# Can not convert from PS to PDF

Tags: ps2pdf

I can not do ps2pdf in my latex..

here is my error.

[image]

when i run from command[image]

Comment: What happens if you try to run ps2pdf from the command line?

Comment: i edit the quest see the message @IanThompson

Comment: The image showed you have called ps2pdf without any argument so it can not convert a file (why did you tag this latex3 and pdftex, neither of which are involved, I retagged to ps2pdf?)

Comment: what do you suggest I do? @DavidCarlisle, how do I make it work?

Comment: If your file is `my.tex` generating `my.ps` then you need the command `ps2pdf my.ps` to generate `my.pdf`

Comment: why are you using latex/dvips/ps2pdf rather than the simpler pdflatex ?

Comment: Thanks a LOT.. it works!! I am using this, as 4 of my pictures have  been cropped when i used directly pdflatex.. when i did ps2pdf it works perfetly.. thanks for the help.

Comment: There should be something wrong in your WinEdt configuration, otherwise you should be able to run ps2pdf directly from within WinEdt...

Comment: yeah i was kinda thinking problem in my Ghostview..:( Do you have a link where i can download full latest Winedit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your file is `my.tex` generating `my.ps` then you need the command

```
ps2pdf my.ps
```

to generate `my.pdf`